# Zend_OpenId_Consumer - Login failed

Tags: zend-framework, openid

I get every time this error, why?

> OpenID login failed!

```
$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer();
if (!$consumer->login('http://openid.org/webo')) {
    die("OpenID login failed!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include http://